# extract a block of lines from a command output in python

Tags: python

I have a command output like following which has block of encrypted codes. How to extract and assign the contents below `block: >`  to a variable. Space before all the lines has to be maintained for the variable. As I am new to python, not sure how to proceed.

```
HlOJsN8A2NSOQGAmhKy30qi7qiIE6qponUZmwJ6fUzFDckBbOMydCui6uY51o91bE4XM8ci+sGqrB6Hvl6JWXASkT7rTLHzpFUTk3ii86aR209bZb8nkEsMT4KQEISSHeJ+NAkGZkbnvISWCwWLVv0wLxAW22DA11C/9cV/fOIrO6VZGzIM69rguMSGObeUKLgDledCf1mFii8WhCA8EChnN3hh4M5RxyCeZhsVSpy3AbkRnMRN2e4T2ISQqblHb7i4+TU0DoVc4aSnCNlgm4pKz7TH6gjA8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHQYJYIZIAWUDBAEqBBA84gFtQxzw2+2Lofkpt/q6gBBA9Y/R7C0tFSl2FxfDUa/I]

OR

block: >
    ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEw
    DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAtcju4aRfjIng9zC/aXQTWYPF/6L8LZufO9GP
    fjhjfhjhjfhjfhjhfjhjhjhfjhjfhjfhjhcagfjgfjfhjkhE6qponUZmwJ6f
    UzFDckBbOMydCui6uY51o91bE4XM8ci+sGqrB6Hvl6JWXASkT7rTLHzpFUTk
    3ii86aR209bZb8nkEsMT4KQEISSHeJ+NAkGZkbnvISWCwWLVv0wLxAW22DA1
    fgjfkhjkfhkjhfjkhjkfhjkhfjkhjkfljlkfhfhkjfhjkhfjkfhjkhfjkhfh
    M5RxyCeZhsVSpy3AbkRnMRN2e4T2ISQqblHb7i4+TU0DoVc4aSnCNlgm4pKz
    vbnbnbjfbjfbjbjfjkhdjhjkfhjkfjkhfjkhjkdhjkhjshwhwjhjkwhjkwhh
    t/q6gBBA9Y/R7C0tFSl2FxfDUa/I]
```

Required output

```
some_var="ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEw
    DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAtcju4aRfjIng9zC/aXQTWYPF/6L8LZufO9GP
    fjhjfhjhjfhjfhjhfjhjhjhfjhjfhjfhjhcagfjgfjfhjkhE6qponUZmwJ6f
    UzFDckBbOMydCui6uY51o91bE4XM8ci+sGqrB6Hvl6JWXASkT7rTLHzpFUTk
    3ii86aR209bZb8nkEsMT4KQEISSHeJ+NAkGZkbnvISWCwWLVv0wLxAW22DA1
    fgjfkhjkfhkjhfjkhjkfhjkhfjkhjkfljlkfhfhkjfhjkhfjkfhjkhfjkhfh
    M5RxyCeZhsVSpy3AbkRnMRN2e4T2ISQqblHb7i4+TU0DoVc4aSnCNlgm4pKz
    vbnbnbjfbjfbjbjfjkhdjhjkfhjkfjkhfjkhjkdhjkhjshwhwjhjkwhjkwhh
    t/q6gBBA9Y/R7C0tFSl2FxfDUa/I]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, you should use `"""multi_line_str"""` if you dont want to see `"\n"` or `"\t"` in your string:

```
origin_str = """block: >
    ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEw
    DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAtcju4aRfjIng9zC/aXQTWYPF/6L8LZufO9GP
    fjhjfhjhjfhjfhjhfjhjhjhfjhjfhjfhjhcagfjgfjfhjkhE6qponUZmwJ6f
    UzFDckBbOMydCui6uY51o91bE4XM8ci+sGqrB6Hvl6JWXASkT7rTLHzpFUTk
    3ii86aR209bZb8nkEsMT4KQEISSHeJ+NAkGZkbnvISWCwWLVv0wLxAW22DA1
    fgjfkhjkfhkjhfjkhjkfhjkhfjkhjkfljlkfhfhkjfhjkhfjkfhjkhfjkhfh
    M5RxyCeZhsVSpy3AbkRnMRN2e4T2ISQqblHb7i4+TU0DoVc4aSnCNlgm4pKz
    vbnbnbjfbjfbjbjfjkhdjhjkfhjkfjkhfjkhjkdhjkhjshwhwjhjkwhjkwhh
    t/q6gBBA9Y/R7C0tFSl2FxfDUa/I]"""
what_you_want_str = origin_str.split("block: >\n")[1].strip()
what_you_want_str
'ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEw\n    DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAtcju4aRfjIng9zC/aXQTWYPF/6L8LZufO9GP\n    fjhjfhjhjfhjfhjhfjhjhjhfjhjfhjfhjhcagfjgfjfhjkhE6qponUZmwJ6f\n    UzFDckBbOMydCui6uY51o91bE4XM8ci+sGqrB6Hvl6JWXASkT7rTLHzpFUTk\n    3ii86aR209bZb8nkEsMT4KQEISSHeJ+NAkGZkbnvISWCwWLVv0wLxAW22DA1\n    fgjfkhjkfhkjhfjkhjkfhjkhfjkhjkfljlkfhfhkjfhjkhfjkfhjkhfjkhfh\n    M5RxyCeZhsVSpy3AbkRnMRN2e4T2ISQqblHb7i4+TU0DoVc4aSnCNlgm4pKz\n    vbnbnbjfbjfbjbjfjkhdjhjkfhjkfjkhfjkhjkdhjkhjshwhwjhjkwhjkwhh\n    t/q6gBBA9Y/R7C0tFSl2FxfDUa/I]'

print(what_you_want_str)
```

output:

```
ENC[PKCS7,MIIBeQYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIBajCCAWYCAQAxggEhMIIBHQIBADAFMAACAQEw
    DQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggEAtcju4aRfjIng9zC/aXQTWYPF/6L8LZufO9GP
    fjhjfhjhjfhjfhjhfjhjhjhfjhjfhjfhjhcagfjgfjfhjkhE6qponUZmwJ6f
    UzFDckBbOMydCui6uY51o91bE4XM8ci+sGqrB6Hvl6JWXASkT7rTLHzpFUTk
    3ii86aR209bZb8nkEsMT4KQEISSHeJ+NAkGZkbnvISWCwWLVv0wLxAW22DA1
    fgjfkhjkfhkjhfjkhjkfhjkhfjkhjkfljlkfhfhkjfhjkhfjkfhjkhfjkhfh
    M5RxyCeZhsVSpy3AbkRnMRN2e4T2ISQqblHb7i4+TU0DoVc4aSnCNlgm4pKz
    vbnbnbjfbjfbjbjfjkhdjhjkfhjkfjkhfjkhjkdhjkhjshwhwjhjkwhjkwhh
    t/q6gBBA9Y/R7C0tFSl2FxfDUa/I]
```